# How to get the count of same value comparing different column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a web form.I want to display the web form if the user hasn't submitted it once. If he had submitted it before the form will not appear. I have a table in sql like this below:

```
| userID | topicId | Date |
|  2     |  1      | 2018 |
|  2     |  5      | 2018 |
|  2     |  4      | 2018 |
|  2     |  8      | 2018 |
|  2     |  9      | 2018 |
```

My form is in `PHP` and I am struggling to write the script which can give me the count of `topicId` submitted by the `userID`. So :

- if the count is less then 1 show him the topic web form;
- if the count is bigger than 1 : don't show him the same topic web form.

So far I have this:

```
 $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(userID) from topicCountTable GROUP BY topicId");
$query->execute();
$row1 = $query->fetchAll();
if (count($row1) >1){
     echo "Sorry you already submitted this topic";
}
else{
        <form>
                 ......
       </form>
 }
```

But for some reason, my script is not working

Comment: Any errors in the browser?

Comment: no there is no error

Comment: I don't think that my logic is right?

Comment: Do you know the userid? Should there be a `WHERE` clause for the `userId`?

Comment: I don't know if we can have an where clause?

Comment: Well, what happens when you have multiple `userID`'s in the database? Given your example, change a few of those `userID`'s to 3. Now think through your logic. Your query will return all, not just for that one `userID`. Your query `COUNT` won't care what the `userID` is and count them all, but you aren't using that anyway. So, do you need to restrict this database query to return only `userID`'s that match a specific user id, or are you building a form with multiple `<form>` markups with all the possible `userID`'s.

Comment: In other words.... We are always glad to help and support new coders but *you need to help yourself first*. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thank you so much @adpro, I think I am clear now. I have multiple forms on the page If the current user has submitted the form no 1 the form number one should disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the query in SQL?

If you're using GROUP BY topic_id and you're looking for a specific topic_id value count, then the topic_id should be in the SELECT part:

`SELECT topicId, count(userID) from topicCountTable GROUP BY topicId`

You probably also want to specify the user_id you're looking for in the query in a WHERE, eg.

`SELECT topicId, count(userID) from topicCountTable WHERE userID = 2 GROUP BY topicId`

Comment: the `group by` statement does not require the grouped element to be in the select

Comment: It does if "you're looking for a specific topic_id value count"

Comment: the userId will depend on the current user who is login

Comment: @MichaelChu, if that's the case then you need to provide more code and use a `WHERE` based on the user ID stored in your session, or whatever you're doing for the logged in user.

Comment: no it does not, just check for yourself here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/45804

the select part just allows you to choose the data you want to get after the query is executed. the `group by` statement will allow you to group data properly when you use aggregate functions

Comment: You are correct, but in @MichaelChu 's code, he's looking for the count for a specific topic id

Comment: there again, the value is not **"necessary"**, it's just better to have it to validate the received data is correct, but the query would still work if the value is not in the select

Comment: Yes, the query would "work", but you wouldn't know what topic_id the counts related to. You'd just get back a set of counts. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I was struggling with the logic on how to select that particular userId from the table base on the current user session and then count if the topicForm is  already submitted or not by the current user

Comment: To get values for a particular Id, you use a `where` or `having` statement. Whether the value is in the select or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you so much@Sirmyself, I think I figure out the solution.